# Executing sql file with sqlplus in windows 10 powershell

Tags: powershell, sqlplus

I have created a .bat file to export csv file regulary through windows task scheduling which works fine.
But not working when I switch to Powershell. It returns (both in ISE and right click .ps1 "Run with Powershell") with:

> SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Sun May 2 14:05:52 2021
> Version 19.10.0.0.0
> Copyright (c) 1982, 2020, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
> ERROR: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

So.I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The variable input are dummies.

In my .bat contains:

> SET NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8
> SET hostIp="123.123.1.12"
> SET username="user1"
> SET password="pass1"
> SET port="1521"
> SET service="myDBname"
> SET sqlPath="C:\My script\TEST_EXPORT.sql"
> sqlplus %username%/%password%@%hostIp%:%port%/%service% @"%sqlPath%"

In my .ps1 contains:

> cls
> $hostIp="123.123.1.12"
> $username="user1"
> $password="pass1"
> $port="1521"
> $service="myDBname"
> $sqlPath="C:\My script\TEST_EXPORT.sql"
> echo "$username/$password@$hostIp`:$port/$service @$sqlPath"
> sqlplus "$username/$password@$hostIp`:$port/$service @$sqlPath"

Comment: The Powershell version is missing double quotes around `$sqlPath`, which the Cmd version has.

Comment: In addition to vonPryz's good find, `$database` in the sqlplus line is not defined anywhere, at least in the code you've given.  Line above it shows `$service` instead of `$database`

Comment: @Daniel Thx. for pointing out. I missed typed that one. Editted with $service. Still getting the same error.

Comment: @vonPryz how should I double quotes areounf the $sqlpath? double quotes within double quotes?

Comment: You're welcome.  Regarding the double quotes, you can double them up or use backtick to escape them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting) to build the parameter string. The upside is that one can build the string and not to worry about quotation issues. Note that there is no need to escape the colon  `` `: `` in the string, as it is not interpreted as scope operator.

```
# A variable that contains double quote
$quote = '"'

$("{0}/{1}@{2}:{3}/{4} @{5}{6}{5}" -f $username, $password, $hostIp, $port, $service, $quote, $sqlPath,$quote)
user1/pass1@123.123.1.12:1521/myDBname @"C:\My script\TEST_EXPORT.sql"
```

Another an alternative for building complex strings is [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). Here are three versions that contain different techniques to include double-quotes. The same works in composite fomatting too.

```
# Double-doublequote version. I'd avoid this, as multiple double quotes are hard to read
"${username}/${password}@{$hostIp}:${port}/${service} @""${sqlPath}"""
user1/pass1@{123.123.1.12}:1521/myDBname @"C:\My script\TEST_EXPORT.sql"
# Backtick-escape version
"${username}/${password}@{$hostIp}:${port}/${service} @`"${sqlPath}`""
user1/pass1@{123.123.1.12}:1521/myDBname @"C:\My script\TEST_EXPORT.sql"
# Quote in a variable version
"${username}/${password}@{$hostIp}:${port}/${service} @${quote}${sqlPath}${quote}"
user1/pass1@{123.123.1.12}:1521/myDBname @"C:\My script\TEST_EXPORT.sql"
```